# Cakephp 3 - Filter access to webroot images

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, controller

i have a folder "files" inside webroot. I need to block the access to this folder (maybe with htaccess), but i need to allow some users to see the images inside. How can i filter the request, take the token from the request (header or post) and allow some users to display images from a mobile app?
I need to create a controller? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dispatch Filters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html). It allows you to conditionally use filters based on request type and then block or change the path of the file served.

The built-in [AssetFilter](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src%2FRouting%2FFilter%2FAssetFilter.php) has a lot of points in common with your question.

Comment: thanks Phillaf. Can i ask you how to return an empty response or a message error for example if user is not logged? Seems that modifying the built-in filter (i have inserted "exit" in all methods) doesn't change nothing and the image continue to be served to the client.

Comment: Seems like the "_getAssetFile($url)" is not triggered when i write the url of an image inside the webroot on browser.. the image is always visible.

Comment: The default .htaccess doesn't go through cake if the the exact file path is used in the url. You could either use a fake path and map the correct assets  path from the filter or remove the 'RewriteCond' line in the .htaccess.

Comment: If you need to check for browser, you can use [isMobile()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent::isMobile). As for authorization, it all depends on your setup. You have access to the session variables and authentication headers. You can [throw errors](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#built-in-exceptions-for-cakephp) or you could stop the rendering process by using [_stopPropagation()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/5eafb81819454358e55b1e6d296e5e81b8d2d5e3/src/Routing/Filter/AssetFilter.php#L82)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm closer to te solution, but if i remove the rewrite conditiion in htaccess, i can't see css and other files anymore.. And request doesn't go through cake..